# cant upload to datastore in ckan 2.5.1: using postgres user instead of configured one

Tags: datastore, ckan

I followed the instructions to install ckan as a package on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I also configured the datastore extension. The databases have been created and the default users and passwords have been configured in /etc/ckan/default/production.ini

My problem is that every time I want to upload a dataset to the DataStore (using the button "Upload to DataStore") it first seems that everything works fine. But if I click somewhere else and click on the DataStore again I get the following red error box:

> Error: CKAN DataStore bad response. Status code: 409 Conflict. At:
>   http://xubuntu12ltsckan/api/3/action/datastore_create. HTTP status
>   code: 409 Response: {"help":
>   "http://xubuntu12ltsckan/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_create",
>   "success": false, "error": {"fields": ["\"2016-01-07 14:35:12 ERROR :
>   Error connecting to the server: FATAL: password... Requested URL:
>   hhttp://xubuntu12ltsckan/api/3/action/datastore_create

(Third url mangled because I don't have the reputation to post more than 2 URLs)

The /var/log/apache2/datapusher.error.log lists these lines:

```
Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error] /usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py:185: SAWarning: Unicode type received non-unicode bind param value '42e50497-2231-4c86-b8db-d...'. (this warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error]   (util.ellipses_string(value),))
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error] Fetching from: http://xubuntu12ltsckan/dataset/f4f9e859-fa6a-4257-8727-32358b448864/resource/d938a82f-95f7-4abd-b982-b32174dfa584/download/pgadmin.log
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error] Deleting "d938a82f-95f7-4abd-b982-b32174dfa584" from datastore.
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error] Determined headers and types: [{'type': u'text', 'id': u'2016-01-07 14:35:12 ERROR  : Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"'}]
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error] Saving chunk 0
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error] Job "push_to_datastore (trigger: RunTriggerNow, run = True, next run at: None)" raised an exception
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 512, in _run_job
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error]     retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 387, in push_to_datastore
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error]     records, api_key, ckan_url)
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 203, in send_resource_to_datastore
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error]     check_response(r, url, 'CKAN DataStore')
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 137, in check_response
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error]     request_url=request_url, response=response.text)
[Fri Jan 22 13:38:24 2016] [error] HTTPError
```

So my problem is that for some reason I don't know ckan tries to connect to the postgres database with the postgres user.

My production.ini instead looks like this:

```
## Database Settings
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:xxx@localhost/ckan_default

ckan.datastore.write_url = postgresql://ckan_default:xxx@localhost/datastore_default
ckan.datastore.read_url = postgresql://datastore_default:xxx@localhost/datastore_default
```

There is no reference to the default database admin user in this file. The role "ckan_default" has CREATE/TEMP/CONNECT privileges and "datastore_default" has CONNECT privileges on the datastore_default database.

I don't see any access constraints here. Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would verify that the production.ini file you're looking at is the one CKAN is really loading.  Take a look in `/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi` and make sure you have:

> `config_filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'production.ini')`

If the host is not in a production environment you can also set `debug = true` in the production.ini (or development.ini), which gives you a helpful debugging interface when an error like this occurs.  It allows you to examine variables at different levels up the stack.  It's very helpful, just don't enable debug on a world-accessible machine.